# Getting error "failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn package]: exit code: 1" on compilation of docker file

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose

i wrote the below code for java code compilation:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build

WORKDIR usr/src/app

COPY . ./

RUN apt-get update && apt -y upgrade

RUN mvn package

FROM tomcat:8.5-jdk8

ARG JAR_NAME="Builder"

COPY DMClient.properties /usr/local/tomcat/bin
COPY DMLogin.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
COPY mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib
COPY DMClient.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/
COPY DMLogin.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/
COPY DMLogin.properties /usr/local/tomcat/bin
COPY sqljdbc_auth.dll /opt/java/openjdk/lib
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD /*.war /DMClient.war

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And on building getting the below error:

```
#0 992.9 [output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn package]: exit code: 1
```

[I tried adding the below code in DockerDesktop Engine:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RYop.png)

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried `COPY *.war /DMClient.war`? Instead of `ADD /*.war /DMClient.war`.

Comment: Can you show the complete output of the `mvn package` command?

Comment: You asked this a couple of days ago.  Please edit your previous question to include the complete error message, not just "exit code: 1"; there's not enough information in either question to understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: I tried COPY *.war /DMClient.war but still getting same error.

Comment: Below is the output where i am getting error:
Progress (3): 2.2/2.5 MB | 1.5 MB | 92 kB    MB | 92 kB
#0 1044.5 [output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn package]: exit code: 1